# Returning a pointer to an array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

So, I'm having a little problem. I'm trying to build a hash table, but I keep getting an error saying "return from incompatible pointer type." I know what this means, but I don't know why my code isn't working. I'm looking for an explanation of why my code does not work. Why does it not recognize the array as a pointer?

I'm making an array of pointers to structs for a hash table. (externally chained)
(I know that my code probably really sucks >< I'm still learning!)

```
struct hashTBL {

    char *userID;
    char *password;
    struct hashTBL *next;
};

typedef struct hashTBL Tbl;
typedef struct hashTBL* TblPTR;

TblPTR createHashTBL(int size)
{
    char *userID;
    char *password;
    int i;

    TblPTR hashArray[size];

    FILE* fpData;
    char *fileName = "encrypted.txt";

    fpData = openReadFile(fileName);

    TblPTR T = NULL;

    while((fscanf(fpData, "%s", userID)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(fpData, "%s", password);
        i = hash(userID, size); 



        if(hashArray[i] != NULL) 
        {
            TblPTR H = hashArray[i];

            while(H != NULL)
            {
                T = H;
                H = H->next;
            }
            H = newPTR(userID, password, T);
        }
        else
        {
            hashArray[i] = newPTR(userID, password, T);
        }

    }
    closeFile(fpData);
    return &hashArray;  
}



TblPTR newPTR(char *userID, char *password, TblPTR T)
{

    TblPTR H = (TblPTR)malloc(sizeof(Tbl));
    if(T != NULL) T->next = H;
    H->userID = userID;
    H->password = password;
    H->next = NULL;

    return H;
}
```

Comment: After a quick look, the code seems valid, though it's hard enough to spot errors in code even when the compilers _do_ tell you which line it's on.  On what line does it fail?

Comment: Please provide a code sample that is as close to compilable as possible, or indicate where the error occurs. I assume `TblPTR` is a typedef for `Tbl*`, but you didn't supply the definition of `Tbl`.

Comment: return statment "return from incompatible pointer type" "function returns address of local variable"

Answer (score 4):

You have at least two problems.

First, your `createHashTBL()` function is defined to return a `TblPTR` object, and you're returning *a pointer to an array* of `TblPTR` objects.  You should change the function type to match the return type you're trying for, or return the right type of object.

Second, your `hashArray` is stack-allocated within the `createHashTBL()` function, which means you can't return a pointer to it.  It will go away when your function returns.  You should try allocating the array with `malloc()` or having the caller provide a pointer to a pre-allocated array.

Comment: You must mean: `hashArray` is *stack-allocated* within `createHashTBL`.

Comment: AH! :) What would the type be for the return pointer exactly? Cause I'm honestly not sure how you would do that.

Comment: Assuming you fix your memory allocation problem, you can just return a TblPTR object to the first element in your array, like this:  return hashArray

Answer (score 2):

`TblPTR hashArray[size];` is created on the stack and cannot be returned, because your variable will be destroyed at the end of your function.

You should use malloc() instead, or `static TblPTR hashArray[size];` (not recommended).

And this is wrong :

```
    return &hashArray;
```

You are returning a pointer to your array : (TblPTR*). Just do

```
    return hashArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler error hints that it might also be another problem too, such as a missing typedef. You should always copy/paste error messages so we can inspect them, as well as indicating which line the error is on in the code you paste - this will help everyone in understanding the problem

There's some errors here though.

```
TblPTR createHashTBL(int size) {

 ... 
 TblPTR hashArray[size];
 ..

 return &hashArray;
}
```

- You cannot return a pointer to a local variable - that variable is gone when the function returns
- createHashTable is declared to return a TblPTR, but return &hashArray; has a completely different type, it's a pointer to an array of TblPTR.

That function should probably be

```
TblPTR *createHashTBL(int size) {

 ... 
 TblPTR *hashArray = malloc(size * sizeof *hashArray);
 ..

 return hashArray;
}
```

(Remember to free() the elements and the hashArray when you're done with it)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems:

1. The type of the expression `&hashArray` is `TblPTR (*)[size]` (pointer to `size`-element array of `TblPTR`), not `TblPTR`; that's where your type mismatch warning comes from.  However, ...
2. `hashArray` is local to the function; as soon as the function exits, `hashArray` is no longer valid, so you'll be returning a pointer to garbage.

A VLA is not the right tool to use here.  I suggest making the following changes:

```
TblPTR *createHashArray(size)       // return a pointer to TblPTR
{
  ...
  TblPTR *hashArray = malloc(sizeof *hashArray * size);
  if (hashArray)
  {
    // initialize hash array as you're currently doing
  }
  return hashArray;
}
```

Note that you'll have to `free()` the array at some point later in your code.